# Texture Painting: How to not have jagged edges when drawing?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm doing texture painting. I get these horrible jagged lines when painting, I want straight lines, what am I doing wrong? How can I do it better, if I can?

Here's some info to help you out:
1. I let the blender handle UV the mesh, so you can consider it auto-uv'ed.
2. I paint straight from a side view but the line goes jagged anyway.
3. Smearing or softening doesn't help.
4. Playing around with "Project Paint" settings didn't help. IE. Occlude, Cull and such.

Can this be a UV issue where the islands are distorted so the paint doesn't go straight?

[image: Jagged Edges when painting, I want straight lines]

Comment: In the Tools panel > Stroke > have you played with the Spacing and Jitter values?

Comment: I did, doesn't fix. Here's an interesting thing I found, if I zoom real far and do the line from the exact same angle, it doesn't go jagged or at least go lessened to acceptable levels. I'm thinking it's something to do with texture or model size.

Comment: perhaps share your file (and pack the image before): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I think the texture map needs to be higher resolution.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6567" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6567/) Hope it helps, not sure if I packed the image correctly tough.

Comment: @Susan, I figured it after I enlarged the texture to 2K, but wasn't sure if it's the solution or the workaround.

Comment: weird because it works fine here

Comment: @moonboots, I'm on some very bad hardware(i5-and-then-some), could that be effecting the drawing?

Comment: I don't think it has to do with your hardware   :/   do you still experience the same problem?

Comment: I scaled the texture to 4K and it got better. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paint on an image that is twice the size you think you need, and you will get the better detail since this is about pixels, and downscale the image with an image editor to get the lower memory version. Make sure your UV mapping has allotted enough pixels for each island - unwrapping technique is critical for small details. In setting up your base image to paint to, perhaps consider checking the option '32 Bit Float' so that you have enough color depth to avoid jagged details, especially when painting bump maps.

Comment: Great help, thanks.